# Get it in action but no display in s:iterator tag

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, actioncontext

I use

```
<class name="Topic" table="topic">     
         .......
  <set name="replies" inverse="true" lazy="false"  cascade="save-update">
        <key column="TOPIC_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="Reply"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

and I have seen replies is not null and have elements in `topic.replies`;

```
Topic topic = topicService.getTopicById(topicId);
ActionContext actionContext = getActionContext();
actionContext.put("topic", topic);
```

and in JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="#topic.replies">
  <s:property value="title"/>
</s:iterator>
```

no title display. 
and then I change my code

```
Topic topic = topicService.getTopicById(topicId);
ActionContext actionContext = getActionContext();
actionContext.put("replies", topic.getReplies);
```

in JSP

```
<s:iterator value="#replies">
  <s:property value="title"/>
</s:iterator>
```

the value of title is displayed.

I don't know why title isn't displayed in first way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replies are configured as lazy, so they are not available until you call `topic.getReplies`. This is actually initializes the lazy collection via accessing entity's proxy. On the other hand you are trying to use OGNL to access the entity and it find it in other way, so the collection is not initialized.

Comment: thanks a lot. but i really configured lazy="false" ,and even though i call topic.getReplies method , title of #topic.replies didn't displayed in jsp.

Comment: @user2245634 topic.getReplies should be called the same session as the topic or you'll get lazyInitializationException.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using ActionContext like that ?

ActionContext is useful for accessing data (already available to the Action) from somewhere else, for example an Helper class, without the need to pass any parameters.

From the documentation: [What is the ActionContext](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/what-is-the-actioncontext.html)

> To keep signatures brief, and methods useful, the framework uses two techniques: *Dependency Injection* and *Thread Local*, both of which, in turn, rely on the *ActionContext*.
>
> From *anywhere* within an Struts 2 application, you can obtain a reference to the [ActionContext] by calling
>
> ```
>   ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
> ```
>
> For example, if a helper class is called from an Action, and if it happens to need access to ServletContext (maybe it is writing a file and needs ServletContext to get a path to it), the helper can obtain the ActionContext directly. Nothing needs to be passed from the Action.

JSP properties are usually read from the Action, and the Action must expose those properties through accessors (or getters); just map your Hibernate result to some DTO in your Action.

Comment: Exactly, use the action context and servlet action context where the action is not available.